# why i am getting No query results for model in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

When i search by city name which is available in my database table it will show the result but when  i search by unknown city which is not available in my database table it says -**No query results for model [App\City].** i am sharing you the code and screenshot [see error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NafTP.png)
actually i want to redirect to 401 page if the city is not found in my database table

Here is my route

Route::get('teacher-jobs-by-city/{city}','TeacherJobsController@by_location');

Here is my function

public function by_location($location_id='')
        {

```
$data= array();
$location = City::where('slug',$location_id)->where('status','1')->firstOrFail();
$items= Subject::orderBy('id','asc')->get();
$data['location']=$location;

      //$subjects = [''=>'Select Subject'] + Subject::lists('subject_title','id')->toArray();
      //$city = [''=>'Select City'] + City::lists('name','id')->toArray();
        $active_class ='Select Subject to see job Openings';
        return view('frontend.teacherjobs.by_location',compact('active_class','data','items'));

    }
```

Answer (score 7):

That's because you are using the `firstOrFail()` method, that as named, fails if theres no result by throwing an Exception that will be redered as "No query results for model ..." message.

If you want to it don't fail, you can:

1. Surround your query with a try-catch block, handling the exception and return some message
2. Replace the `firstOrFail()` method by `first()`

Comment: $location = City::where('slug',$location_id)->where('status','1')->first();  Now i am getting  Trying to get property of non-object (View: /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/esythink/public/local/resources/views/frontend/teacherjobs/by_location.blade.php)

Comment: of course you focus on this line : ```$location = City::where('slug',$location_id)->where('status','1')->firstOrFail();``` and because you're doing a firstOrFail() you need to handle the Exception when the location *isn't found*. When the object *$location* isn't there, you will get errors, so make sure that $location is found.

Answer (score 6):

You can handle that kind of error by modifying the way `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException` Exception are handle. In the `App\Exceptions\Handler` class change the render method to look like this

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException){
        return redirect("/error_page", 401)->with('error', $e->getMessage());
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Within the redirect your must put the route to which you want to be redirected, I put `/error_page` just for sample purpose.
You can learn more on [Error Handling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/errors)'

Don't forget to import the ModelNotFoundException like this `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;`

Answer (score 2):

Adding on to the answer by Elias Soares, This happens because laravel generates an "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException" exception if firstOrFail don't return results.

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#retrieving-single-models

It's upto you how you want to handle this exception. If using firstOrFail -> to first() solution

After replacing firstOrFail with first, You would get the error: "Trying to get property of non object", That's because your query didn't fetched anything, so it won't have attribute. For that you can place a check on the results of your query.

```
$location = City::where('slug',$location_id)->where('status','1')->first();

!empty($location->attribute)?$location->attribute:null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
$location = City::where('slug',$location_id)->where('status','1')->firstOrFail();
```

With this:

```
$location = City::where('slug',$location_id)->where('status','1')->first();
```

Comment: i had done the same as you said, but getting error    Trying to get property of non-object (View: /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/esythink/public/local/resources/views/frontend/teacherjobs/by_location.blade.php)

Comment: you could dd( $location );
to see what property is null